# Ubuntu Server 16.10 Static Networking - Unable To Raise Interface

Tags: networking, 16.10, vpn, static-ip

I need some assistance as I am going nuts trying to figure this out. I have been running static networking with a split tunneling setup using this guide: https://www.htpcguides.com/force-torrent-traffic-vpn-split-tunnel-debian-8-ubuntu-16-04/ This setup has been working for a while (3 or so months) until I replaced a switch with a new one and added in some new cables. I am not sure how had any effect on the interfaces but for some reason, it isn't wanting to load up the interface any longer. I have included some info below to assist.

This is my current /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
address 192.168.0.30
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

# Secondary NIC Interface
auto eno2
iface eno2 inet static
address 192.168.0.31
netmask 255.255.255.0

# Auto IPV6
iface eno1 inet6 auto
iface eno2 inet6 auto
```

This is the printout I get from ifconfig:

```
journey@ubuntu1:~$ ifconfig -a
eno1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 
      inet 192.168.0.30  netmask:255.255.255.0 broadcast:192.168.0.255
      inet6 fe80::226:b9ff:fe47:b411 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x20 <link>
      ether 00:26:b9:47:b4:11  txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
      RX packets:0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
      RX errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:236  bytes 20479 (20.4KB)
      TX errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0
      device interrupt 16

eno2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 
      inet 192.168.0.31  netmask:255.255.255.0 broadcast:192.168.0.255
      inet6 fe80::226:b9ff:fe47:b412 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x20 <link>
      ether 00:26:b9:47:b4:12  txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
      RX packets:3029  bytes 602269 (602.2 KB)
      RX errors:0 dropped:567 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:168  bytes 27982 (27.9 KB)
      TX errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0
      device interrupt 17

lo:   flags=4163<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> mtu 65536
      inet 127.0.0.1  netmask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 scopeid 0x10 <host>
      loop  txqueuelen 1 (Local Loopback)
      RX packets:63452  bytes 6432026 (6.4 MB)
      RX errors:0 dropped:567 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:63452  bytes 6432026 (6.4 MB)
      TX errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0
```

Now here is my ip addr output:

```
journey@ubuntu1:~$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
   link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
   inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
   link/ether 00:26:b9:47:b4:11 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
   inet 192.168.0.30/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eno1
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   inet6 fe80::226:b9ff:fe47:b411/64 scope link 
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
   link/ether 00:26:b9:47:b4:12 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
   inet 192.168.0.31/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eno2
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   inet6 fe80::226:b9ff:fe47:b412/64 scope link 
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

So far, I cannot ping either Google or the gateway (192.168.0.1). 100% Packet Loss. I also see that the VPN isn't connecting and it's adding an additional 5 min to boot time cause it is failing to raise network interfaces.

I also want to note, that i have another server running off the same switch with an almost identical interfaces file and it is working perfectly fine (Yes, it also has a split vpn setup done the exact same way). See that interface file here (Note, this is a Ubuntu 16.04 server instead of 16.10, and a clean install with just the split tunneling configured):

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
address 192.168.0.33
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

# Secondary NIC Interface
auto eno2
iface eno2 inet static
address 192.168.0.34
netmask 255.255.255.0

# Auto IPV6
iface eno1 inet6 auto
iface eno2 inet6 auto
```

Any insight that can be added would be really appreciated as I am at a loss of what to try next. Thank you!

Edit 1:

Outputs as requested:

```
journey@ubuntu1:~$ ip r l
192.168.0.0/24 dev eno1  proto kernel  scope link  scr 192.168.0.30 linkdown
192.168.0.0/24 dev eno1  proto kernel  scope link  scr 192.168.0.31

journey@ubuntu1:~$ sudo mii-tool eth0
SIOCGMIIPHY on 'eth0' failed: No such device

journey@ubuntu1:~$ sudo mii-tool eth1
SIOCGMIIPHY on 'eth1' failed: No such device

journey@ubuntu1:~$ sudo mii-tool eno1
eno1:no link

journey@ubuntu1:~$ sudo mii-tool eno2
eno2: negotiated 1000baseT-FD flow-control, link ok
```

Comment: There is something wrong in the sources you posted. On both servers, the ip addresses in the network configuration are the same (.33 and .34), but `ifconfig` on the first server shows .30 and .31. What is correct then?

Comment: @ridgy apologies. So the server that is working is listed as .33 and .34. The server that isn't working is configured as .30 and .31. I have made the changes in the post to show correct.

Comment: Can u pls post the output of the command "ip r l" and the output of "sudo mii-tool eth0" ?

Comment: @StancuMihai added requested outputs to main post.

Comment: Can u try pls to move the ethernet cable from eno2 to eno1 and check again with sudo mii-tool eno1 to see if the link comes up?

Comment: And please leave the eno2 without any cable plugged in whilest you have the eno2 previously connected cable to eno1. The main purpose of this is to see if there is a network card related problem or switch related. If you have link on eno1 with the same cable that was plugged previously in eno2, then you need to check if the cable that was plugged in eno1 does work in eno2 ( again, without any cable plugged in eno1 ) and if it does have link in eno2 means that there is no issue with your cables and there is a huge possibility to have a loop in your switch or something missconfigured. We will se

Comment: As u can see in your recently posted output, you don't have link on eno1, and because of that, no default gateway is configured ( in your network settings the default gateways interface is eno1 ), so it's normal not to reach Google's server.

Comment: @StancuMihai looks like it's a cable issue. Replacing the eno1 cable with the eno2 cable and grabbing a different cable got me back up and running. I didn't even think to check the cables since I saw activity on the switch and they were brand new cables. Thanks so much for the help in solving it!!